# How to denote the comma as an element of a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have a set whose elements include the comma character ",". But the comma is used as a separator when listing the elements of a set. Any suggestions for a sensible notation to use in this case?

Comment: Just replace the character "," by a letter which does not appear in the set. Do all calculations and at the end replace that particular letter by the character "," .

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? What is this set exactly?

Comment: Give an example, would you please; it can only help people answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you talk about comma being an element of a set and if character means something typed on a keyboard and not  about a representation of a group then you are likely to be involved in computer programming.

Define your set using ASCII code as  $\{ \mathtt{chr}(x) \mid x\in A\}$ where $A$ is the set of ASCII values of your character set and $\mathtt{chr}$ is the function (as in Python language),  mapping an  ASCII valtue to a character.  There are no commas in this description. And $A$ is a set of positive integers which can be written out with comma as separator.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. My original post was motivated exclusively by a notational dilemma. I do not need to do any computations. I was discussing with a friend how the punctuation of a sentence can greatly change its meaning. A well-known example is:

Comment: Eats, shoots, and leaves.
versus
Eats shoots, and leaves.
In that spirit I was discussing (in writing) how one can rearrange the words and punctuation signs of, for example, the sentence:
"Hi dear, love, me."
I was asking: how many different sentences can one make rearranging the elements of the set {hi, dear, love, me, ","}
when I realized I did not know how to handle the comma as an element of the set. I then wondered if there is a standard way of handling this situation purely from the notational point of view.

Comment: As this was posted with "Elementary Set Theory" as a tag I thought of answering that. Anyway this is the problem when we use symbols: do we interpret it as the object it symbolizes or the do we interpret it as a symbol? In highschool I had a friend whose   answers to  questions of the type, "Form a sentence using the following word: ***" was very simple: "It is very difficult to form a sentence with  ***"